Retrieve Issue on Cost Management Activity log
enter image description here
this is the activity log
enter image description here
and here is the sample response on api activity log
so the goal to get the exact wording just like on first image
how to do that ?
right end url to get the activity log on cost management
Navigation
Cost Management > Cost > Number > Activity log

The detailed activity log you see on the UI/web they have been formatted from the API response you are showing. All the data you require to present the log as you wish is available in the API response: See the image:

You can map the response to any format you wish.
